# Add Date and Author to node.tpl.php

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-6, themes, drupal-theming

In the code below I'd like to show the created date, author and have them be linked but nothing for they do not show. I believe I need to be doing `$node->` rather that row, haven't figured out the exact code. Or what if anything I need to change under Views in my Drupal 6 installation. Thanks in advance!

```
<?php if($node->type == 'blog'): ?>
  <div class="blog-page">
    <div class="title-post">
        <div class="top-image">
            <?php print $node->field_image[0]['view'] ?>
        </div><!--TOP-IMAGE-->
        <p>Posted on <a href="<?php $row['path'] ?>">?php $row['created'] ?></a>, by 
        <a href="<?php print url('blog/author/'.$row['uid']) ?>"><?php print $row['name'] ?></a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-page">
        <?php print $node->content['body']['#value'] ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
<?php print $content ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal has a node object with tons of related information in it. Basically if you ever need to use information from it like author, date, title, etc, you can easily determine the code by printing the node object.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($node);
echo '</pre>';
```

lets say it outputted something like this for simplicity's sake:

```
stdClass {

  nid = 3
  content = stdClass {
           raw = " ... "
           clean = " ... "
        }

}
```

To output those bits of information in your template, you'd write in the following way.

for a field with no subclass:

```
<?php print $node->nid ?>
```

for a field with a subclass:

```
<?php print $node->content['raw'] ?>
```

Does that make sense? after you get that down, you literally can figure out anything when programming drupal templates.

so, if you wanted to construct a url, you'd just chain it up:

```
<?php
  $nid = $node->nid;
  $uri = "some/path".$nid;
  print $uri;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, echoed the node values but still having a problem figuring how to display the data I need. The results to that echo are here: http://www.pastie.org/2117237 The created date shows a long string of numbers even though in the view it has it formatted properly and in all other views the date shows in the proper format. Also what the link would be for the author and such.

Comment: Those dates you see there are timestamps (time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch = January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT). To get a "normal" date from them you need to pass them through PHP's date() function, for example:

    date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row->created);

See more on available formats here: http://php.net/date

Comment: Maciej, Thanks but doesn't work. IT says the date is December 31st, 1969. But I logged into that article and it shows it is "2011-05-20 00:00:00 -0400". Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out. Just needed to change your $row to $node.